# How to call particular function in a C source file from a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, c

I have a C source file with some functions in it. I want to call some particular function from a shell script.
I have a `sample.c` file with the below content. I want to call `funcA` here from a shell script. How can I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void funcA(void){
    printf("Congrats..!! This is function A...!!\n");
}


int main(void){
    printf("Better luck next time..!!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to call a function from a C binary/library directly from shell. Some languages support this (for example Python with [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)) but I don't know any similar option for bash (or other shells).

You'll need to use command line options options and call the C program with an option/argument that tells your program to call a specific function.

So for your example you'll need to do something like

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {

   if (argc != 2) {
      printf("Argument expected\n");
      return 1;
   }
   
   if (strcmp (argv[1], "funcA") == 0)
      funcA();
}
```

And then you can call it from shell like

```
$ ./a.out funcA
Congrats..!! This is function A...!!
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to change your code a bit by adding a call to the `exit` function (e.g. `exit(0);`) at the end of the functions, you can compile your code by passing the `-e funcA` option to the linker to make their entry point `funcA` in this case.

Assuming the file being called `foo.c`, you can then have the following shell script which executes the `funcA` function from the file `foo.c` upon calling `call foo.c funcA` from a shell script.

```
call() {
    cc -Wl,-e"$2" $1 && ./a.out
}
```